# How to determine the place of a row in ordered SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users and a 'points' column. I would like to determine the number/place of the row across all the users ordered by 'points'.

I could just get result of all users data and then do while loop, and stop when id equals necessary user. But I believe there is a more efficient way do to that because my table will contain ~100 000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select sub.*, sub.rank as Rank
FROM
(
   Select *,  (@rownum:=@rownum+1) as rank
   FROM   users
   ORDER BY points 
) sub
WHERE rank = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the row number of your record

[Here's](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) a good way to do it in MySQL

It would look like this

```
SELECT rank_user.* 
FROM 
(
   SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* 
   FROM user u, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r   
   ORDER BY points DESC
) rank_user 
WHERE rank BETWEEN 2 AND 4;
```

Comment: But if I want to retrieve only 1 row, not a table - then it shows rank = 1 all the time.
Sorry. Deleted the comment by mistake.

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal answer is doing what you want. I will edit mine also